# Como tratar erros de caso o usuário insira um caractere inválido?

Tags: python, while

Eu queria fazer nas parte da entrada de notas, e na parte final de mostrar as notas de cada aluno individualmente, algo parecido com o que fiz na parte de 'Quer continuar? [S/N]', ou seja, só avançar de etapa, caso o usuário entre com um número válido. porque da forma que tá aí, caso seja inserida uma nota inválida, ou seja, strings ao invés de inteiros, ou eu peça pra ver as notas de um aluno que não existe na lista, ele dá erro e encerra o programa. aí queria blindar ele desses bugs. porém já tentei usar o loop infinito,o loop com condição de parada, mas nada funciona. aguardo resposta. e segue meu código abaixo:

````
nota = []
aluno = []
while True:
    pessoa = input('Nome do aluno: ').capitalize()
    while True:
        n1 = str(input('Nota 1: '))
        if n1.isnumeric == False:
            break
    while True:
        n2 = str(input('Nota 2: '))
        if n2.isnumeric == False:
            break
    aluno.append(pessoa)
    nota.append(n1)
    nota.append(n2)
    aluno.append(nota[:])
    geral.append(aluno[:])
    aluno.clear()
    nota.clear()
    while True:
        opç = str(input('Quer continuar?[S/N] ')).lower().strip()[0]
        if opç in 'sn':
            break   
    if opç == 'n':
        break
print(14 * '-=')
print(f'{"Num°":<2}{"Aluno":^10}{"média":>11}')
print(14 * '-=')
for pos,c in enumerate(geral):
    print(f'{pos:<6}{str(c[0]):<14}{sum(c[1])/2:3}')
print(14 * '-=')
while True:
    num = int(input('De qual aluno deseja saber as notas?[999 para encerrar] '))
    if num == 999:
        break    
    print(f'As notas de {geral[num][0]} foram {geral[num][1]}')
print('Volte sempre, tenha um bom dia!')```
````

Answer (score 1):

Tem vários problemas aí, o primeiro é:

```
if n1.isnumeric == False
```

Você não está chamando o método `isnumeric`. Na verdade, você está comparando se o próprio método é falso, o que nunca será, então o programa fica em *loop* nesta parte. Para chamar o método, precisa de parênteses (`n1.isnumeric()`), mas ainda sim a lógica é falha, pois você só entra no `if` se não for numérico, que é o oposto do que você quer.

De qualquer forma, há vários caracteres para os quais `isnumeric` retorna `True` mas dão erro ao converter para `int`, [veja aqui](https://ideone.com/BjUfXE). O melhor seria fazer logo `int(entrada)` e capturar o `ValueError` para saber se não foi digitado um número (mais ou menos [assim](https://ideone.com/pMJ7Ph)).

Outro detalhe é que `input` já retorna uma string, então fazer `str(input())` é redundante e desnecessário. Mas se quer que a nota seja um número, guarde-a logo como número mesmo.

E não precisa criar várias listas, e ficar adicionando elementos nelas e depois limpando-as. Você pode guardar tudo em um dicionário, que mapeia cada nome para suas respectivas notas:

```
# função que lè um número
def ler_numero(mensagem):
    while True: # enquanto não digitar um número, continua no loop
        try:
            return int(input(mensagem))
        except ValueError:
            print('Digite um número')

alunos = dict() # cria um dicionário de alunos
while True:
    nome = input('Nome do aluno: ').capitalize()
    n1 = ler_numero('Nota 1: ')
    n2 = ler_numero('Nota 2: ')
    alunos[nome] = [n1, n2] # mapeia o nome do aluno para as suas notas
    while True:
        opç = input('Quer continuar?[S/N] ').lower().strip()[0]
        if opç in 'sn':
            break   
    if opç == 'n':
        break

print(14 * '-=')
print(f'{"Num°":<2}{"Aluno":^10}{"média":>11}')
print(14 * '-=')
for pos, (nome, notas) in enumerate(alunos.items()):
    print(f'{pos:<6}{nome:<14}{sum(notas) / len(notas):5.2f}')
print(14 * '-=')
while True:
    aluno = input('De qual aluno deseja saber as notas?[999 para encerrar] ').capitalize()
    if aluno == '999':
        break
    if aluno in alunos: # verifica se o aluno existe no dicionário
        print(f'As notas de {aluno} foram {alunos[aluno]}')
    else:
        print(f'Não temos as notas de {aluno}')

print('Volte sempre, tenha um bom dia!')
```